# Fetch data after given createdAt date

Tags: postgresql, graphql, postgraphile

I want to fetch data of last one hour.

I have doubt how to add `>` && `<` in postgraphile?

if I add current_timestamp in double quotation still getting error.

Here is postgraphile screen.

[image]'hour in postgraphile

Answer (score 4):

You can read about [filtering in the PostGraphile docs](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/filtering/). To achieve what you've specified you could use the [postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter](https://github.com/graphile-contrib/postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter) plugin, and issue a query such as this:

```
query SessionsSince($timestamp: DateTime!) {
  allSessions(filter: {
    createdAt: { greaterThan: $timestamp }
    deviceid: { equalTo: "123" }
  }) {
    ...
  }
}
```

However, please keep in mind that a GraphQL API is not intended to expose all the functionality of your database to your users. Rather than exposing this raw interface, I'd personally use a [custom query](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/custom-queries/) which would expose a much neater API; something like:

```sql
create function recent_sessions(deviceid text) returns setof sessions as $$
  select *
  from sessions
  where sessions.deviceid = recent_sessions.deviceid
  and created_at > NOW() - interval '1 hour';
$$ language sql stable;
```

You'd then query it like this:

```
{
  recentSessions(deviceid: "123") {
    nodes {
      deviceid
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 2020 update; an alternative approach is to add a custom condition via https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/make-add-pg-table-condition-plugin/